Extension of a property of complex numbers to higher dimensions.
We have the following result about complex numbers (see, e.g. Rudin RCA Lemma 6.3): Let $z_1,\dots, z_N$ be complex numbers. Then there exists a subset $S\subset\{1,\dots, N\}$ so that $$\left|\sum_{k\in S} z_k\right|\geq \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^N |z_k|.$$ That is, one can dominate the sum of norms of a finite list of complex numbers by the norm of the sum of a subset at the cost of a constant. My question is whether the following statement, or some specialization of it is true:
Let $x_1,\dots,x_N$ be elements of some Banach space $X$. Then there exists a constant $C>0$ not depending on $N$ and a set $S\subset\{1,\dots, N\}$ so that $$\left\|\sum_{k\in S} x_k\right\|\geq C\sum_{k=1}^N \|x_k\|.$$ The result from Rudin uses the fact that $$\sup_{S\subset\{1,\dots, N\}}\left|\sum_{k\in S} z_k\right|=\sup_{\theta\in[0,2\pi]} |z_k|\cos^+(\alpha_k-\theta),$$ where $z_{k}=|z_k|e^{i\alpha_k}$. I don't see an analogue of this even in $\mathbb{C}^n$, so I am unsure of how to proceed with proving such a thing, and searching for counterexamples has been fruitless so far.

I think for general Banach spaces this is not true: Consider the (real or complex) Banach space $X=l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ endowed with the supremum norm, and let
$e_k:=(\delta_{kn})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. If here such a constant $C>0$ exists we would get
$$
1=\left\|\sum_{k \in S_N}e_k\right\| \ge C \sum_{k=1}^N \|e_k\| = CN
$$
for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with a set $S_N \subseteq \{1\dots,N\}$. A contradiction.
The same idea works in the Hilbert space $l^2(\mathbb{N})$. Then
(with $|S_N|$ the number of elements of $S_N$)
$$
\sqrt{N}\ge \sqrt{|S_N|}=\left\|\sum_{k \in S_N}e_k\right\| \ge C \sum_{k=1}^N \|e_k\| = CN,
$$
hence $C\sqrt{N} \le 1$ for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$, again a contradiction.

Excellent! This makes sense in hindsight—I believe I was able to show the result holds in $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the constant not depending on $N$ but depending on $n$, more specifically with the constant being $Cn^{-1/2}$ for some absolute constant $C$. If I have the time in the coming days I will edit the proof into the body of the post.
